# Start selenium server 2.39.0, but when running test, it turns out to be selenium server 2.35.0

Tags: selenium

I started selenium server: selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar, but when running test, the instance turns out to be selenium remote control v2.35.0. 
I have ever used v2.35.0, but now i want to upgrade it to v2.39.0 to avoid some issues.

Can somebody be kindly to help? Thanks in advance!
I am trying to attach a image, but i cann't, as i have no enough reputation.

Comment: can you post the code that you use to start the server

Comment: This is the code that i used to start the server: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar

Comment: btw are you running the scripts from command line? in that case check whether your class path has the latest version.

Comment: i run the test scripts using VS2010 + Gallio3.4, do i need to config the class path?  BTW, I have ever used v2.35.0, but now i want to upgrade it to v2.39.0 to avoid some issues.

Comment: yes just update the config path to point to the latest selenium version(2.39.0)

Comment: Can you please give some guidelines about the configuration? i remember when using v2.35.0, i did no config.